# Proof of the continuity of a bilinear

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Could somebody please verify the following proof I have attempted? Thank you in advance.

---

Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. the bilinear form $a : H^1(\Omega) \times H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:bilinear}
    a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} (k \nabla u) \cdot \nabla v \,\mathrm{dx} \quad \forall (u, v) \in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2, 
\end{equation}
where $k\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Show that $a(u,v)$ is continous.

---

**Proof.**
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}|a(u,v)| &= \left|\int_{\Omega}(k \nabla u)\cdot\nabla v\, \mathrm{dx}\right|\quad,\forall (u, v)\in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2\\
\quad\\
&\underset{\text{C-S}}{\leq} \left[\int_{\Omega}(k\nabla 
u)^2\mathrm{dx}\right]^{1/2}\cdot\left[\int_{\Omega}(\nabla v)^2\mathrm{dx}\right]^{1/2}, \quad\forall (u, v)\in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2
\end{align*}
Note that $\|u\|_{H^1} = \|u\|_{L^2} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$, therefore $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{H^1}$, which is the same for $v$, hence we obtain
\begin{align*}
|a(u,v)| &\leq \|k\|_{L^{\infty}}\left[\int_{\Omega} (\nabla u)^2\mathrm{dx}\right]^{1/2}\cdot\left[\int_{\Omega}(\nabla v)^2\mathrm{dx}\right]^{1/2},\quad\forall (u, v)\in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2\\
\quad\\
&= \|k\|_{L^{\infty}}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}\|\nabla v\|_{L^2}, \quad\forall (u, v)\in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2\\
\quad\\
&\leq \|k\|_{L^{\infty}}\|u\|_{H^1}\|v\|_{H^1},\quad\forall (u, v)\in \left[H^1(\Omega)\right]^2.
\end{align*}
Thus, $a$ is bounded, which implied the continuity of $a(u,v)$.

Comment: you forgot the absolute values $|a(u,v)|$ in the second set of calculations, but yes, this is it (or you can just say “by Cauchy-Schwarz” once one develops confidence :) The key is that $k\in L^{\infty}$

Comment: Ah thank you very much

Comment: Also, there is no "t" in Cauchy-Schwarz. This is the German mathematician Hermann Schwarz (1843-1921), not the French mathematician Laurent Schwartz (1915-2002).

Comment: Oh my fault, thank you so much